# Convergence in Schwartz Space of Fourier transforms?

Tags: convergence-divergence, fourier-transform, schwartz-space

Let $f_n$ a sequence in Schwartz space. Suppose that $\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ { \left\| { f }_{ n }-f \right\|  }_{ \alpha ,0 }=0 } $, where ${ \left\| f \right\|  }_{ \alpha ,0 }=\underset { x\in R }{ \sup } { \left| x \right|  }^{ \alpha  }\left| f\left( x \right)  \right|$. Is it true that its Fourier transforms converge  in the same sense, in others words $\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ { \left\| \widehat { { f }_{ n }-f }  \right\|  }_{ \alpha ,0 }= } 0$ or not?

Comment: No as a bound for  $\|\widehat{f}\|_{\alpha,0}$ for every $\alpha$ gives a bound for $\|f\|_{0,m}$ for every $m$